# flat для обьекта на JS

Tags: javascript

```
  const options = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nestedOptions: [
        { id: 2 },
        { id: 3 },
        { id: 4 }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      nestedOptions: [
        { id: 6 },
        { id: 7 },
        { id: 8 }
      ]
    },
  ]
```

Как можно промапить масив в такую структуру?

```
const options = [
{ id: 1 },
{ id: 2 },
{ id: 3 },
{ id: 4 },
{ id: 5 },
{ id: 6 },
{ id: 7 },
{ id: 8 },
]
```

Comment: Есть же [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: @Adrug, он тут не совсем подходит, из-за поля `id`

Comment: Сколько уровней вложенности?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для уменьшения вложенности массива есть функция [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), который в коллбэке позволяет получать вложенную коллекцию, однако обычное его применение тут не поможет

```js
const options = [{
    id: 1,
    nestedOptions: [{
        id: 2
      },
      {
        id: 3
      },
      {
        id: 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    nestedOptions: [{
        id: 6
      },
      {
        id: 7
      },
      {
        id: 8
      }
    ]
  },
]

console.log(options.flatMap(o => o.nestedOptions))
```

Как видно из примера, отсутствуют промежуточные `id`, которые лежат непосредственно в объекте. Поэтому их нужно добавить руками в возвращаемый массив

```js
const options = [{
    id: 1,
    nestedOptions: [{
        id: 2
      },
      {
        id: 3
      },
      {
        id: 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    nestedOptions: [{
        id: 6
      },
      {
        id: 7
      },
      {
        id: 8
      }
    ]
  },
]

console.log(options.flatMap(({nestedOptions,id}) => [{id}, ...nestedOptions]))
```

Comment: Это будет работать с одним уровнем вложенности? Или не? И если не сложно, прокомментируй решение ниже. Интересно твоё мнение.

Comment: @AlexSazonov, это работает именно как описано, берутся массивы, которые возвращаются в коллбэках и объединяются в один.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вариант с рекурсией. Но я бы очень хотел услышать мнение насчёт этого варианта. Потому как тут ещё и IIFE, и замыкания... В общем, как-то хз, правильно ли это?

```js
const options = [
{
  id: 1,
  nestedOptions: [
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 },
    { id: 4 }
  ]
},
{
  id: 5,
  nestedOptions: [
    { id: 6 },
    { id: 7 },
    { id: 8 }
  ]
},
];

function flat(arr) {
  let res = [];
  
  !function innerFlat(arr) {
    arr.forEach((item, index) => {
      for(let k in item) {
        Array.isArray(item[k]) ? innerFlat(item[k]) : res.push({[k]: item[k]});
      }
    });
  }(arr);
  
  return res;
}

console.log('res', flat(options));
```

Comment: вот это плохое место: `res.push({id: item[k]});` - ты с одной стороны делаешь общее решение, с другой в результате жестко забиваешь только объект со свойством `id`, причем со значением, которое может быть любому свойству равно

Comment: @Grundy спасибище! Исправил. В остальном это валидный подход для решения такой задачи? Просто я уже, честно признаться, 2 года за деньги пишу на js, и это первый раз, когда мне пригодилось понятие замыканий :) Не уверен, что сегодня это актуальный метод.

Comment: я бы сказал, что это один из подходов для обхода дерева. Сам бы делал скорее в всего другую реализацию без inner функции и forEach, но в принципе и данный вариант имеет право на жизнь